# Why is the basis the same for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Why is the basis the same for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$?

Here is the basis I am talking about: $\left \{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\right \}$.

Would the set $\left \{1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6},\sqrt{18}\right \}$ be another valid basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$?

Comment: $\sqrt {18} = 3\sqrt 2$  so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {18})$ and $Q(\sqrt {2})$ are the same field.

Comment: Sure, $\sqrt{18}$ is a scalar multiple of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Since $\sqrt {6} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ you don't need to include it with $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ as it is redundent.

Comment: @fleablood We're talking about a basis for $Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ as a vector space over $Q$. So $\sqrt 2 \sqrt 3$ is not a linear combination of basis vectors, since neither are in $Q$. We need $\sqrt 6$ (or some multiple) in the basis.

Comment: One thing: why the basis is just $\{1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 6\}$ for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vectors space? How would you find the combination of $\sqrt {3/2}, \sqrt {2/3}$ using the "basis"? The fields are identical, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would also be valid because you've just scaled $\sqrt{2}$. The two fields have the same basis because of proofs such as $\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt3 =\sqrt6$.  Hence the fields are equal.